# Image not displaying in close response

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lex

I want to display clickable images of my social links to user in response card, in AWS console those images are displaying (although click is not working) but when the bot is integrated with website those images are not displaying.

I am using python 2.7 for Lambda code.

```
response = {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Close',
            'fulfillmentState': fulfillment_state,
            'message': message,
            'responseCard': {
            'version': '0',
            'contentType': 'application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic',
            'genericAttachments': [
                {
                    'title': 'Follow us on Twitter',
                    'subTitle': 'Twitter',
                    'attachmentLinkUrl': 'https:someurl1',
                    'imageUrl': 'someimage1.png'

                },
                {
                    'title': 'Follow us on Facebook',
                    'subTitle': 'Facebook',
                    'attachmentLinkUrl': 'https:someurl',
                    'imageUrl': 'someimage.png'

                },
                {
                    'title': 'Follow us on Medium',
                    'subTitle': 'Medium',
                    'attachmentLinkUrl': 'https:someurl',
                    'imageUrl': 'someimage.png'

                },
                {
                    'title': 'Follow us on Youtube',
                    'subTitle': 'Youtube',
                    'attachmentLinkUrl': 'https:someurl',
                    'imageUrl': 'someimage.png'

                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the built in Channels that are configured in the Lex Console? What channel are you attempting to use?